# Socketio object undefined when it's passed to child component in React, typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, socket.io, react-state-management

I have this piece of code which is basically a WIP page for simple chat application I'm working on as a part of my faculty course.

I'm getting socket from the server and I'm able to use it on the main component with no problems, but it's always `undefined` in the child component.

Main component:

```
import React, { FormEvent } from 'react';
import { asyncConnect } from '../utils/index';
import { 
  socketEvents, 
  SendActiveUsersMessage
} from '../types';
import { Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
import Home from './Home';

export default function RegisterUser() {  

  let socket: typeof Socket;
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState<string>("");
  const [badUsername, setBadUsername] = React.useState<boolean>(true);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = React.useState<string>("");
  const [signupSuccessful, setSignupSuccesful] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  
  const handleSubmit = async (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {

    event.preventDefault();

    if (username === "") {
      setBadUsername(true)
      return;
    } else {
      setBadUsername(false);
    }

    socket = await asyncConnect();
    if(!socket) {
      setErrorMsg('Backend unreachable');
    }

    socket.emit(socketEvents.SEND_USERNAME, {
      username
    });

    socket.on(socketEvents.SEND_ACTIVE_USERS, (msg: SendActiveUsersMessage) => {
      console.log('activeUsers: ', msg.activeUsers);
    });
    
    setSignupSuccesful(true);

  }

  const handleInputChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setUsername(e.currentTarget.value);
  }
  
  const generateErrorMessageIfNeeded = () => {
    
    let error = errorMsg;
    
    if (badUsername) {
      error += "User name must not be empty\n";
    }
    return (
      <h3>{error}</h3>
    )

  }

  const generateInputForm = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h2>Enter username</h2>

          <input 
            type='text'
            id='username'
            onChange={handleInputChange} 
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div>{generateErrorMessageIfNeeded()}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  const render = () => {
    if(signupSuccessful) {
      return <Home socket={socket as typeof Socket}/>
    } else {
      return generateInputForm();
    }
  }
  return render();
}
```

`asyncConnect` function looks like this:

```
import io, { Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
import { socketEvents } from '../types';

export const asyncConnect = async():Promise<typeof Socket> => {
  return new Promise( (resolve, _reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const socket = io.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL as string);
      socket.on(socketEvents.CONNECT, () => {
          resolve(socket)
      });
    }, 500)
  });
}
```

`Home` component, to which I'm passing socket to, looks like this:

```
import { Socket } from "socket.io-client"

interface Props {
  socket: typeof Socket
}

export default function Home (props: Props) {  
  
  console.log('props from Home component: ', props);
  return (    
    <h2>Home </h2>
  )
}
```

#### Saving socket to state

Another thing I've tried is to create state for the socket (similarly to 4 already existing ones). But when I try to do that, after I save the state and try to use the socket which is inside of the state I get `socket.emit is not a function` error.

Any kind of help is appreciated, because I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You do not initialize your socket to a value until the form submit event is fired.  Even once it has been initialized due to the way react works if the component is rerendered it will be lost because it is not persisted as state.

This is an unusual way to use socket.io. It feels like you are trying to slot it into a place where you would typically use ajax.  Usually you would expect to init a websocket at near page load to begin listening to any potential server pushed events. I would say you should consider initing the websocket outside of your react components and pass it in to the initial call.  You usually don't want the rendering of a component to do something like start a persistent connection.

Consider migrating to a pattern where instead of passing the websocket you use callbacks to fire the events.  This helps keep components simple and well defined.

Ex

`return <Home submitForm={submitForm}/>`

Comment: I've implemented it with `useEffect()` hook now, in the first component that is mounted, and everything seems to be working okay. But I"m still getting new sockets created whenever I reload the page, while I'm aware that that's the expected behaviour is this the correct way to do it?

I've tried to use redux store to permanently save sockets but they cannot be saved to local storage since they have circular references, and libraries which should handle that are just not working properly.

Comment: You can't save a socket across page loads.  Sockets are not state that is managed by your application and treating them as such is a mistake.